Show bijectivity of $f: (0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto\frac{x^2-1}{2x}$
How do I formally show that
$$
f: (0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto\frac{x^2-1}{2x}
$$
is bijective?
Surjectivity:
I solve $y=\frac{x^2-1}{2x}$ for $x$ so that $x\in (0,\infty)$. This is the case for
$$
x=y+\sqrt{y^2+1}.
$$
Now, I should get $f(y+\sqrt{y^2+1})=y$:
$$
f(y+\sqrt{y^2+1})=\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}+\frac{y\sqrt{y^2+1}}{y+\sqrt{y^2+1}}
$$
Does that give $y$? Don't see it.
Injectivity:
Suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, that is
$$
\frac{x_1^2-1}{2x_1}=\frac{x_2^2-1}{2x_2}
$$
I have to conclude that $x_1=x_2$. I think this is a consequence of the fact that by definition $x_1,x_2$ are positive.

Sorry, unsure how you're getting that expression for $f(y + \sqrt{y^2 + 1})$, e.g. $2$ doesn't appear. You should have $\dfrac {(y^2 + 2 y \sqrt {y^2 + 1} + (y^2 + 1)) - 1} {2(y + \sqrt {y^2 + 1})}$. This simplifies to $y$ and you get surjectivity. For injectivity, you can look back at your proof deriving the inverse and notice that you can use "iff"s (your working will work both forwards and backwards)

For the injectivity part: let $s,t>0$ such that $f(s)=f(t)$. This means: $\frac{s^2-1}{2s}=\frac{t^2-1}{2t} \implies s-\frac1s=t-\frac1t \implies s-t+\frac{s-t}{st}=0$. Can you conclude?

$f(x) = \sinh(\ln x)$. $\ln$ is a bijective  mapping from $(0, \infty)$ to $\Bbb R$, and $\sinh$ is a bijective mapping from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.

@MartinR A one-line proof. Fantastic observation :).

@S.H.W: Yes, but it is cheating: An elementary proof of the bijectivity of $\sinh$ leads again to the equation $y = (x+1/x)/2$, making this a circular argument.

@MartinR You are right. It seems that there is no elementary way to make it non-circular.

Injectivity:
Suppose that $$\frac{x_1^2-1}{2x_1}=\frac{x_2^2-1}{2x_2},$$ holds. Then, $$x_2x_1^2-x_2 = x_1x_2^2 - x_1 \implies x_1x_2(x_1-x_2)+(x_1-x_2) = 0 \\ \implies (x_1-x_2)(x_1x_2+1) = 0.$$ The case $x_1x_2 = -1$ is impossible since $x_1,x_2 \gt 0$. So we have, $$x_1 = x_2.$$
Surjectivity: Let $$y = \frac{x^2-1}{2x}.$$So we have $$x^2-2xy-1 = 0 \implies x = \frac{2y\pm\sqrt{4y^2+4}}{2}.$$ Since $4y^2+4\ge 0$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$, this shows that for each $y\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y = f(x)$. We have to show that this $x$ can be a positive number. Indeed, for $y\ge 0$ it's obvious that $2y+\sqrt{4y^2+4}\gt 0$, so $x\gt 0$. For $y\lt 0$, we have $$\sqrt{4y^2+4} \gt \sqrt{4y^2} = 2|y| \implies -2|y|+\sqrt{4y^2+4} \gt 0 \implies 2y+\sqrt{4y^2+4} \gt 0,$$ and again this shows that $x \gt 0$.
